# C#: How to set query result to combo box in datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a datagrid in which i have combobox in a column. On a particular event i want to populate the combo box with result of the query. I wrote this code

```
string materialQuery = "Select material_name from tbl_material_master where material_id =" + int.Parse(mat_id);
            cmd1 = new SqlCommand(materialQuery, con);
            sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (sdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    materialName = sdr["material_name"].ToString();
                    grdPurchase.Rows[0].Cells[2] = materialName.ToString();
                }
            }
```

But it gives error
How do i fix this?

Comment: Did you try doing only materialName = sdr.ToString(); ? Or ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader ? ( I don't know how ExecuteReader works )

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza `ExecuteNonQuery` is used for Insert, Update and Delete queries.  Not very useful though for a Select query.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't know it, thanks ! ( I was using an ExecuteNonQuery with a Select query, so I'm going to change it ! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no data errors, try adding the items to the `Items` collection of the ComboBox:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell;
cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)grdPurchase.Rows[0].Cells[2];
cell.Items.Add(materialName);
```